# deal button shouldn't work whilst blackjack dealer bot is running

Tags: javascript, blackjack

I have a blackjack challenge which looks like this:

[image]

I've programmed a sleep function so that when the bot is playing it can space out its moves over a few seconds rather than all at once. When I click "stand" and the bot is playing I can't click the hit button, but I can click the "deal" button which means everything resets but I don't want the deal button to work while the bot is playing-it should be disabled just like the hit button is.

Anyone know what's going on and why my deal button still works when the bot is playing? Much appreciated.

My sleep function:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

The asynchronous dealer logic function:

```
async function dealerLogic() {
blackjackGame['isStand'] = true;

while (DEALER['score'] < 16 && blackjackGame ['isStand'] === true) {
let card = randomCard();
showCard(card, DEALER);
updateScore(card, DEALER);
showScore(DEALER);
await sleep(1000);
}
if (DEALER['score'] > 15) {
    blackjackGame['turnsOver'] = true;
    let winner = computeWinner();
    showResult(winner);
    console.log(['turnsOver']);
}




}
```

Blackjack deal button function:

```
function blackjackDeal() {


    if (blackjackGame['turnsOver'] === true) {
    blackjackGame['isStand'] = false;    
    let yourImages = document.querySelector('#your-box').querySelectorAll('img');
    let dealerImages = document.querySelector('#dealer-box').querySelectorAll('img');
    

    for (i=0; i < yourImages.length; i++) {
        yourImages[i].remove();
    }


    for (i=0; i < dealerImages.length; i++) {
        dealerImages[i].remove();} 
    
    

YOU['score'] = 0;
DEALER['score'] = 0;

document.querySelector('#your-blackjack-result').textContent = 0;
document.querySelector('#your-blackjack-result').style.color = 'white';

document.querySelector('#dealer-blackjack-result').textContent = 0;
document.querySelector('#dealer-blackjack-result').style.color = 'white';

document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').textContent = "Let's play";
document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').style.color = 'black';

blackjackGame['turnsOver'] = true;
}
    }
```

The entire javascript:

```
//Challenge 5: Blackjack

let blackjackGame = {

'dealer': {'scoreSpan': '#dealer-blackjack-result', 'div': '#dealer-box', 'score': 0},  
'you': {'scoreSpan': '#your-blackjack-result', 'div': '#your-box', 'score': 0},   
'cards': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'K', 'J', 'Q', 'A'],
'cardsMap': {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'K': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'A': [1, 11]},
'wins': 0,
'losses': 0,
'draws': 0,
'isStand': false,
'turnsOver': true,

};


const YOU = blackjackGame['you']
const DEALER = blackjackGame['dealer']

const hitSound = new Audio('static/sounds/swish.m4a');
const winSound = new Audio('static/sounds/cash.mp3');
const lossSound = new Audio('static/sounds/aww.mp3');

document.querySelector('#blackjack-hit-button').addEventListener('click', blackjackHit);
document.querySelector('#blackjack-stand-button').addEventListener('click', dealerLogic);
document.querySelector('#blackjack-deal-button').addEventListener('click', blackjackDeal);

function blackjackHit() {  
 if (blackjackGame['isStand'] === false) { 
let card = randomCard();
showCard(card, YOU);
updateScore(card, YOU);
showScore(YOU);} }


function randomCard() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    return blackjackGame['cards'][randomIndex];
    }


function showCard(card, activePlayer) {
    if (activePlayer['score'] <= 21) {
    let cardImage = document.createElement('img');
    cardImage.src = `static/images/${card}.png`;
    document.querySelector(activePlayer['div']).appendChild(cardImage);
    hitSound.play(); }  
}

function blackjackDeal() {


    if (blackjackGame['turnsOver'] === true) {
    blackjackGame['isStand'] = false;    
    let yourImages = document.querySelector('#your-box').querySelectorAll('img');
    let dealerImages = document.querySelector('#dealer-box').querySelectorAll('img');
    

    for (i=0; i < yourImages.length; i++) {
        yourImages[i].remove();
    }


    for (i=0; i < dealerImages.length; i++) {
        dealerImages[i].remove();} 
    
    

YOU['score'] = 0;
DEALER['score'] = 0;

document.querySelector('#your-blackjack-result').textContent = 0;
document.querySelector('#your-blackjack-result').style.color = 'white';

document.querySelector('#dealer-blackjack-result').textContent = 0;
document.querySelector('#dealer-blackjack-result').style.color = 'white';

document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').textContent = "Let's play";
document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').style.color = 'black';

blackjackGame['turnsOver'] = true;
}
    }





function updateScore(card, activePlayer) {


if (card === 'A') {

    if (activePlayer['score'] + blackjackGame['cardsMap'][card][1] <= 21) {
activePlayer['score'] += blackjackGame['cardsMap'][card][1];

}  else { 

activePlayer['score'] += blackjackGame['cardsMap'][card][0];}



} else {

activePlayer['score'] += blackjackGame['cardsMap'][card];
}
}

function showScore(activePlayer) {

if (activePlayer['score'] > 21) {
    document.querySelector(activePlayer['scoreSpan']).textContent = 'BUST!';
    document.querySelector(activePlayer['scoreSpan']).style.color = 'red';
    
}

else {
document.querySelector(activePlayer['scoreSpan']).textContent = activePlayer['score'];
}

}


function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function dealerLogic() {
blackjackGame['isStand'] = true;

while (DEALER['score'] < 16 && blackjackGame ['isStand'] === true) {
let card = randomCard();
showCard(card, DEALER);
updateScore(card, DEALER);
showScore(DEALER);
await sleep(1000);
}
if (DEALER['score'] > 15) {
    blackjackGame['turnsOver'] = true;
    let winner = computeWinner();
    showResult(winner);
    console.log(['turnsOver']);
}




}

function computeWinner() {
    let winner;

if (YOU['score'] <= 21) {
if (YOU['score'] > DEALER['score'] || (DEALER)['score'] > 21) {
blackjackGame['wins']++;
winner = YOU;

} else if (YOU['score'] < DEALER['score']) {
    blackjackGame['losses']++;
    winner = DEALER;

} else if (YOU['score'] === DEALER['score']) {
    blackjackGame['draws']++;
    

}

} else if (YOU['score'] > 21 && DEALER['score'] <= 21) {
    blackjackGame['losses']++;
    winner = DEALER;

} else if (YOU['score'] > 21 && DEALER['score'] > 21) {
    blackjackGame['draws']++;
    



}


console.log(blackjackGame);

return winner;
}

function showResult(winner) {
    let message, messageColor;

    if (blackjackGame['turnsOver'] === true) {
    
    if (winner === YOU) {
    document.querySelector('#wins').textContent = blackjackGame['wins'];    
    message = 'You won';
    messageColor = 'green';
    winSound.play();
    


} else if (winner === DEALER) {
    document.querySelector('#losses').textContent = blackjackGame['losses']; 
    message = 'You lost';
    messageColor = 'red';
    lossSound.play();

} else {
    document.querySelector('#draws').textContent = blackjackGame['draws']; 
    message = 'You drew';
    messageColor = 'black';
}

document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').textContent = message;
document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').style.color = messageColor;
    }


}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container-5"> 

<h2>Blackjack Challenge</h2>
<h3><span id="blackjack-result">Let's Play</span></h3>

<div class="flex-blackjack-row-1">
    <div id="your-box">
        <h2>You: <span id="your-blackjack-result">0</span></h2>
    </div>
<div id="dealer-box">
    <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-blackjack-result">0</span></h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-blackjack-row-2">
    <button class="btn-lg btn-primary mr-2" id="blackjack-hit-button">Hit</button>
    <button class="btn-lg btn-warning mr-2" id="blackjack-stand-button">Stand</button>
    <button class="btn-lg btn-danger mr-2" id="blackjack-deal-button">Deal</button>
</div>


<div class="flex-blackjack-row-3">
   
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Wins</th>
            <th>Losses</th>
            <th>Draws</th>
        </tr>

<tr>
    <td><span id="wins">0</span></td>
    <td><span id="losses">0</span></td>
    <td><span id="draws">0</span></td>
    
</tr>

    </table>

</div>


</div>








<script src ="static/script.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.container-5 {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-blackjack-row-1, .flex-blackjack-row-2 
{
display: flex;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
color: #ffffff;
background: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/poker-table-background-green-color_47243-1068.jpg') center;}


.flex-blackjack-row-3 {

    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;    

}


.flex-blackjack-row-1 div {

border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
height: 350px;
text-align: center;
flex: 1;
}

.flex-blackjack-row-1 img {

    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flex-blackjack-row-2 button {

border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}

.flex-blackjack-row-2 div {

border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}


table, th, td {

padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;

}






.flex-blackjack-row-2 {
    display: flex;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```